# Is an instance method recalculated every time they are used on a page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, load

I have the following instance method for my model "Page".

```
def voted?(ipaddress)
  self.iparray.include? ipaddress
end
```

Basically it looks through an array to see if it already contains the user's ip address. Would `voted?` have to be recalculated for every piece of code that checks if it is true, like this?

```
<% if voted? %>
  ....
```

Or would it be saved as `true` or `false` on page load, and then that value would be passed through the conditionals?

**This question isn't a duplicate because the other question was asking if instance methods are recalculated on every page load. This question is asking if they are recalculated every time they are used on a page.**

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding the depth of this question.  If you are saying if you check for `voted?` further up in the page then every other `if` statements are going to inherit it then, no that is incorrect.  Read on Ruby branching.  If however you are referring to query being "re-executed" then AFAIU ActiveRecord caches the queries.  So consecutive calls are read from cache.  But is `iparray` an AR column?

Comment: @vee In other words, is `voted?` set to `true` or `false` at the start of page load, and then `true` or `false` are passed through the `if` statements? Or does the value of `voted?` have to be calculated every time the logic reaches an `if` statement?

Comment: @muistooshort They belong to the same topic, but they are all different questions.